# Can I use mastic to apply stone to an interior wall sheathed with OSB?

Tags: stone, thinset, veneer, mastic

I am in the process of building out a man cave. I have selected MSI split marble stacked  stone for the bar. The bar is L shaped approx 40 1/2” high.

What are the pros/cons of using mastic to apply stone directly to the OSB fascia sheeting rather than the traditional Hardie board and thinset route?

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se], please take the [tour]. I edited your question to better fit with the model here for questions so that someone can give you an actual answer. I'm sure someone, somewhere has done what you're asking about so the answer to the question you implied was "yes". That probably doesn't do you much good though... :)

Comment: Also, you might want to [edit] your question to indicate _why_ you want to do this. Things are normally done certain ways for good reason and deviations, while possible, often come with unintended consequences.

Comment: Read the adhesive instructions. They always blacklist OSB from what I've seen. It's odd, though, because the OSB has the same Exposure 1 rating as plywood with the X shorthand (the X indicates Exposure 1, not Exterior grade). I always figured it was because of the OSB's swelling from water.

Comment: Unlike plywood, OSB is not a continuous surface and subject to small area delamination.